# How to convert Powershell to Python for AD group creation

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, active-directory

I have a Powershell  command

```
New-ADGroup -Name "Group_Name" -SamAccountName Group_Name -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Group_Name" -Path "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"
```

I am trying to convert it into this python code (using ldap)

```
...
attrs = dict(sAMAccountName=group_name)
attrs.update(GroupCategory=1)
attrs.update(GroupScope='Global')
attrs.update(DisplayName=group_name)
attrs.update(Path='CN=Users,DC=devfactory,DC=local')
connection = self.create_ad_connection(ad_server)
entry = connection.add(distinguished_name, object_class='group', attributes=attrs)
...
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred: LDAPAttributeError
invalid attribute type GroupCategory
```

How can I set **GroupCategory**  and other attributes on python? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does `GroupCategory` translate to in LDAP? I don't see that attribute in any LDAP model i can find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `GroupCategory` (also known as "Group Type") and the `GroupScope` are both set in [the `groupType` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-grouptype), which is a bitmask (or bitflag): a binary value where each bit is an on/off flag with a different meaning. The [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-grouptype#remarks) of the `groupType` documentation tells us that the 2<sup>nd</sup> bit is what makes it a global group, and the 32<sup>nd</sup> bit (decimal value of 2,147,483,648) is what makes it a security group.

If you want to set it to a global security group, you can set the `groupType` attribute to the sum of the two decimal values: 2 + 2147483648 = 2147483650

```
attrs.update(groupType=2147483650)
```

The binary value looks like this:

```
10000000000000000000000000000010
```

The two 1's are what make it a global security group.

Comment: thanks, but now I am getting the same error text for the Path attribute. Do you know what should be used for the Path? or any docs for that?

Comment: 'Path' isn't really an attrribute. The OU should be part of `distinguished_name`. That's what tells it which OU to create it in.